# Scraping the Divar.ir

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've wrote a code to scrape the [Divar](https://divar.ir/), which is an equivalent of Ebay in Iran. I have a few questions:

- Am I doing the error handling and logging ok?
- Is there a better way to optimize this code? (note that the API is limited to 30 calls in a minute for page retrieval, but isn't limited by the post retrieval)
- What's the best way to cache the data that has already been scraped before?

Here's the code:

```
import concurrent.futures
import datetime
import json
import logging
import os
from time import sleep

import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, HTTPError, RequestException
from urllib3.exceptions import MaxRetryError


def fetch_json_data(token):
    url = f'{BASE_URL}/posts/{token}'
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.json()
    except RequestException as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to fetch data for token {token}: {str(e)}")
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to decode JSON for token {token}: {str(e)}")

def fetch_and_save_post(token, category, city_code):
    j = fetch_json_data(token)
    if j:
        save_json(j, category, city_code, token)
        
def save_json(j, category, city_code, token):
    json_path = f"{RESULTS_DIR}/category_{category}__city_{city_code}"
    with open(f'{json_path}/{token}.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(j, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
        logging.info(f"Saved: {token}")
        print(f"saved {token}", end="\r")

def retrieve_page(url, json_payload, headers, MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS):
    for _ in range(MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS):
        try:
            start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            res = requests.post(url, json=json_payload, headers=headers)
            res.raise_for_status()
            response_time = (datetime.datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds()
            
            # Adjust sleep time dynamically based on response time
            sleep_time = max(0.6, 2 - response_time)
            sleep(sleep_time)
            return res.json()
        except (RequestException, MaxRetryError, ConnectionError, HTTPError) as e:
            logging.error(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
            sleep(2)

def date_to_unix(DTS): 
    return int(datetime.datetime.strptime(DTS, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp()) * 1_000_000

def scrape(city_code, category, date_time_str, MAX_PAGES, MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS):
    unix_timestamp = date_to_unix(date_time_str)
    last_post_date = unix_timestamp

    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/search/{city_code}/{category}"

    page_count = 1

    try:
        while page_count <= MAX_PAGES:
            json_payload = {
                "json_schema": {
                    "category": {"value": category}
                },
                "last-post-date": last_post_date,
                "page": page_count
            }

            data = retrieve_page(url, json_payload, headers, MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS)

            if data is None:
                break

            if not data.get("web_widgets", {}).get("post_list"):
                break

            post_list = data["web_widgets"]["post_list"]
            
            # TODO Use ThreadPoolExecutor for parallel scraping at the post level
            with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
                futures = []

                for post in post_list:
                    if "action" in post["data"]:
                        if "token" in post["data"]["action"]["payload"]:
                            token = post["data"]["action"]["payload"]["token"]
                            futures.append(executor.submit(fetch_and_save_post, token, category, city_code))

                for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                    pass  # TODO I can add any post-level processing here if needed

            last_post_date = data["last_post_date"]
            logging.info(f"Page {page_count} scraped. Last post date = {last_post_date}")
            page_count += 1

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logging.info("Scraping interrupted by user.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An unexpected error occurred: {str(e)}")



if __name__ == "__main__":

    BASE_URL = "https://api.divar.ir/v8"
    RESULTS_DIR = "Results"
    category="apartment-rent"
    city_code=2
    
    # Configure logging
    json_path = f"{RESULTS_DIR}/category_{category}__city_{city_code}/"
    if not os.path.exists(json_path):
        os.makedirs(json_path)
    logging.basicConfig(filename=json_path+"scrape_log.log", level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    
    scrape(city_code=city_code, category=category, date_time_str="2023-09-11 10:30:00", MAX_PAGES=4, MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS=5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an overall pleasant code to read. A bit of oddities here and there but nothing to be afraid off.

## Logging

You're using the root logger for each of your calls, that may be fine for this purpose but if you ever try to reuse part of this code as a module, it may be unnecessary cumbersome to reconfigure / disable these logs. As such, logs are usually handled through the logger returned by `logging.getLogger(__name__)`. This way, it is easier to repurpose through a call of

```
logging.config.dictConfig({
        'version': 1,
        'formatters': {'divar': {'format': '=> %(message)s'}},
        'filters': {},
        'handlers': {'divar': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler', 'formatter': 'divar'}},
        'loggers': {'divar': {'level': 'INFO', 'handlers': ['divar']}},
})
```

or disable completely with `dictConfig({'version': 1, 'loggers': {'divar': {'handlers': []}}})` (assuming the module is named `divar`). This makes it far easier for users of your code to configure the logs to **their** needs.

And speaking of logs, I really don't like the line `print(f"saved {token}", end="\r")`. It is so great that you're using logging to not clutter the output of your code unnecessarily, just continue doing so. Use another logger if necessary and configure a `logging.StreamHandler` for it if you really want to see these messages, but do not print here. Even better, since you are now both logging **and** printing, you can consolidate the code to a single `logger.info` call, as long as the new logger is a child of your `__name__` logger and propagate the messages.

I also like to define a top-level function:

```
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=1)
def getLogger():
    return logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Although not really necessary since `logging` already caches the loggers it creates, I find it removes a bit of clutter from the code and ease overall readability.

## Requests

A few quick comments about your usage of `requests`:

1. Using the `json` parameter of a request automatically adds the `Content-Type: application/json` header, you don't need to add it yourself
2. Using a `requests.Session` to perform your requests allows to reuse connections and reduce network-related overheads
3. As I started using a `Session` in the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, I got some warnings from `urllib3` that the default connection pool was getting full and some requests were dropped: consider using [an adapter](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter) that suits your needs.
4. While on the topic of adapters, consider using an [`urllib3.Retry`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.Retry) object instead of rolling your own retry mechanism. Interesting parameters for you seems to be `total`, `status_forcelist` and `backoff_factor`. Or even, consider rolling your own subclass to always get a retry delay of 2 seconds.

## Download folder and caching

I like to use `pathlib.Path` instead of `os.path` for managing the filesystem. I find it easier to, for instance, pass a folder around that I can create or explore whenever I see fit. I also like the utility methods such as `.open` on files that tend to remove some clutter compared to the more verbose `os.path`.

So consider creating your destination folder and pass it as a parameter to the `fetch_and_save_post` / `save_json` functions. This will simplify writing the output file and you can also check, before the download, if the destination file already exist.

## Command line arguments

There are a few parameters, in your code, that I feel are meant to be changed regularly, based on context.

It would feel better if these parameters were parsed from the command-line (with sensible defaults) so it is easier to change them. For this purpose, the [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) is a decent first step that will allow you to call your script using syntax such as

```
$ python divar.py
$ python divar.py --max-pages 5 --city-code 5
$ python divar.py -c cats -d OutputFolder -t "2023-06-01 00:00:00" -r 7
```

## Proposed improvements

```python
import json
import logging
import argparse
import concurrent.futures as parallel

from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep, perf_counter
from functools import lru_cache

import requests
from requests.exceptions import BaseHTTPError, RequestException


POST_LOGGER = f'{__name__}.post'
WAIT_TIME_BETWEEN_RETRIES = 2.0  # API limits to 30 pages call per minutes


class Retry(requests.urllib3.Retry):
    def get_backoff_time(self):
        return WAIT_TIME_BETWEEN_RETRIES


@lru_cache(maxsize=1)
def getLogger():
    return logging.getLogger(__name__)


def build_api_url(*route, unparse=requests.utils.urlunparse):
    route = Path('/v8').joinpath(*route)
    return unparse(('https', 'api.divar.ir', route.as_posix(), '', '', ''))


def download_post(session, token, folder):
    logger = logging.getLogger(POST_LOGGER)
    destination = folder.joinpath(f'{token}.json')
    if destination.exists():
        logger.info("Skipping token %s: file already exists", token)
        return

    try:
        response = session.get(build_api_url('posts', token))
        response.raise_for_status()
        post = response.json()
    except RequestException as e:
        getLogger().error("Failed to fetch data for token %s: %s", token, e)
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        getLogger().error("Failed to decode JSON for token %s: %s", token, e)
    else:
        with destination.open('w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(post, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
            logger.info("Saved: %s", token)


def retrieve_page(session, url, payload):
    try:
        response = session.post(url, json=payload)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.json()
    except (RequestException, BaseHTTPError) as e:
        getLogger().error("An error occurred: %s", e)


def extract_tokens(posts):
    for post in posts:
        try:
            token = post['data']['action']['payload']['token']
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            pass
        else:
            yield token


def scrape(city_code, category, last_post_date, result_directory, max_pages, max_retries):
    search_url = build_api_url('search', str(city_code), category)
    last_post_date = int(last_post_date.timestamp() * 1_000_000)

    session = requests.Session()
    retries = Retry(total=max_retries, allowed_methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries, pool_block=True)
    session.mount('https://api.divar.ir/', adapter)

    sleep_time = 0
    for page_count in range(1, max_pages + 1):
        sleep(sleep_time)
        json_payload = {
            'json_schema': {
                'category': {'value': category}
            },
            'last-post-date': last_post_date,
            'page': page_count
        }

        start_time = perf_counter()
        data = retrieve_page(session, search_url, json_payload)
        try:
            post_list = data['web_widgets']['post_list']
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            break

        with parallel.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            futures = [
                    executor.submit(download_post, session, token, result_directory)
                    for token in extract_tokens(post_list)
            ]

            for future in parallel.as_completed(futures):
                # TODO I can add any post-level processing here if needed
                pass

        last_post_date = data['last_post_date']
        getLogger().info("Page %d scraped. Last post date is %d.", page_count, last_post_date)

        # Adjust sleep time dynamically based on response time
        elapsed_time = perf_counter() - start_time
        sleep_time = max(0.2, WAIT_TIME_BETWEEN_RETRIES - elapsed_time)


def command_line_parser():
    def date_parser(user_input):
        return datetime.strptime(user_input, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    parser.add_argument('--category', '--cat', '-c',
                        default='apartment-rent',
                        help='category of posts to search for')
    parser.add_argument('--city-code', '--city', '--code', '-z',
                        type=int, default=2,
                        help='...')
    parser.add_argument('--result-directory', '--directory', '-d',
                        type=Path, default=Path('Results'),
                        help='Directory in which to store scraping results')
    parser.add_argument('--last-post-date', '--date', '--time', '-t',
                        type=date_parser, default=datetime.now(),
                        help='...')
    parser.add_argument('--max-pages', '--pages', '-p',
                        type=int, default=4,
                        help='Amount of pages to scrape for')
    parser.add_argument('--max-retries', '--retries', '-r',
                        type=int, default=5,
                        help='Amount of time a request will be retried when a download fails')
    return parser


def main(argv=None):
    args = command_line_parser().parse_args(argv)

    folder = args.result_directory.joinpath(f'category_{args.category}__city_{args.city_code}')
    folder.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    # Configure logging
    logging.basicConfig(
            filename=folder.joinpath('scrape_log.log').as_posix(),
            level=logging.INFO,
            datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    logging.getLogger(POST_LOGGER).addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

    args = vars(args)
    args['result_directory'] = folder
    try:
        scrape(**args)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        getLogger().info("Scraping interrupted by user.")
    except Exception as e:
        getLogger().error("An unexpected error occurred: %s", e)
        raise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```